# Error in fetching data from weather API. Typeerror: cannot read property of undefined in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to make a simple weather application from FCC weather API.

I am able to get the location and trying to access the temp property from the JSON file but while doing so, I am getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined".

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="weatherApp">
  <head>
    <title>Weather App in Angular</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/arunisrael/angularjs-geolocation/master/dist/angularjs-geolocation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="weatherAppController">
      <h1>Weather App</h1>
      Your latitude is: {{coords.lat}}
      Your longitude is: {{coords.long}}
      <p> The Temperature is : {{temperature}} </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the controller code

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  angular.module('weatherApp', ['geolocation'])
    .controller('weatherAppController', weatherAppController);
  weatherAppController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'geolocation'];
  function weatherAppController($scope, $http, geolocation){
    geolocation.getLocation().then(function(data){
      $scope.coords = {lat: data.coords.latitude, long: data.coords.longitude};
      $http.get('https://fcc-weatherapi.glitch.me/api/current?lat='+$scope.coords.lat+'&lon='+$scope.coords.long)
        .then(successCallback);
      function successCallback(data){
        $scope.temperature = data.main.temp;
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }
})();
```

Comment: What that means is your data.main is null.

Comment: did ypou consoled the `data` variable

Comment: Yeah, I did consoled the data variable and it is showing that I am receiving an object.

Comment: Change this line `then(successCallback)` to `then(function(response) { successCallback(response); })` , You are not actually passing the response to your callback function.

Comment: No,  It's not working.
Here is what I did:
.then(function(response){
      successCallback(response);
    });
    function successCallback(data){
      $scope.temperature = data.main.temp;
      console.log(data);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angularJS when a callback function is called it passes an object with additional information, and actual data is returned with "data" property.
in your code you just use
 `$scope.temperature = data.data.main.temp;`
this will be worked.

final code is -

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  angular.module('weatherApp', ['geolocation'])
    .controller('weatherAppController', weatherAppController);
  weatherAppController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'geolocation'];
  function weatherAppController($scope, $http, geolocation){
    geolocation.getLocation().then(function(data){
      $scope.coords = {lat: data.coords.latitude, long: data.coords.longitude};
      $http.get('https://fcc-weatherapi.glitch.me/api/current?lat='+$scope.coords.lat+'&lon='+$scope.coords.long)
        .then(successCallback);
      function successCallback(data){
        $scope.temperature = data.data.main.temp;
        console.log($scope.temperature);
      }
    });
  }
})();
```

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the call back function as below,

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('weatherApp', ['geolocation'])
    .controller('weatherAppController', weatherAppController);
    weatherAppController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'geolocation'];
    function weatherAppController($scope, $http, geolocation){

        $scope.coords = {lat: 35, long: 139};
        $http.get('https://fcc-weatherapi.glitch.me/api/current?lat=35&lon=139')
        .then(function(response) { 
          console.log(response);
          $scope.temperature = response.data.main.temp;
        });
    }
    })();
```

For simplicity, I have removed the geolocation call, but you can keep it in your version. A working code is available [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/PvzfzsjX0p9o1TzBpGPe?p=info)

Comment: Yeah, it's working now but can you please tell me that why we are using that "data"

Comment: When Angular calls back the 'callback' function, it passes an object with many information like response header, http status code, etc. and the actual data returned is within the property 'data'. Checkout [here](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp) for the complete structure of the response object.